# How do I know that which user has done buying operation in php

Tags: php, session

I want use the payment gateway in my site. Also I created in my `login.php` a session variable to get the user session id.

**login.php**

```
     <?php 
session_start();        
//get the data from the fileds;
        //check it.
        //and if it was correct, create a session id like the below
        //$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
        //redirect to the send.php
        ?>
```

Now, I have three php file for buying operation. Please see the following code:

**send.php**

```
<?php
include_once("sender.php");
$url = 'http://example.com/payment/gateway-send';
$api = ' Your-API ';
$amount = 1000;
$redirect = 'REDIRECT-PAGE';
$result = send($url,$api,$amount,$redirect);
if($result > 0 && is_numeric($result)){
$go = "http://example.ir/payment/gateway-$result";
header("Location: $go");
}
?>
```

**get.php**

```
<?php
include_once("sender.php");
$url = 'http://example.com/payment/gateway-result-second';
$api = ' Your-API';
$trans_id = $_POST['trans_id'];
$id_get = $_POST['id_get'];
$result = get($url,$api,$trans_id,$id_get);
?>
```

**sender.php**

```
<?php
function send($url,$api,$amount,$redirect){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"api=$api&amount=$amount&redirect=$redirect");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $res;
}
function get($url,$api,$trans_id,$id_get){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"api=$api&id_get=$id_get&trans_id=$trans_id");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $res;
}
?>
```

My question is, How I should use the existing session in `login.php` in this three file?

I have three variable `to have the amount` and `to have the API value that Have given from payment gateway to me` and `the REDIRECT-PAGE`. When the user inters in site using the his username and password, the variable be send to the payment gateway and if the values of variables were correct, the payment gateway sends the `$result` and if there was `if($result > 0 && is_numeric($result))` so `$go` variable gets the `$go = "http://example.com/payment/gateway-$result";` and then the user can see the payment page and he can buy.

If the purchase was successful, the payment gateway sends to `get.php` the `trans_id` and `id_get` variables and then if they ware correct, I should save the  **buyer username** and the `trans_id` and the `id_get`. How I should use the session in the three php file??

Comment: Use a persistent store (a database) for a purchase. And don't touch real payment APIs until you do...

Comment: For starters you must start the session initially on every page. Secondly, what's so complicated? You initialize a session variable and you read from it wherever you want (as long as you have an initialized session) and do whatever you want with it. Start with something simpler, just page A and page B and read and write to session variables.